# focus a particular cell after make clicking alert box in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I wanna create  a focus on a particular cell value after clicking the alert box in jqgrid please any one suggest a solution thanks in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body { font-size: 75%; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
            $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          var lastsel2;
          var myGrid = $('#rowed5');
          var selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
          var celValue = myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'columnName');
          jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({        
            datatype: "local",
            height: 250,
            colNames:['ID Number','Name', 'Stock', 'Ship via','Notes'],
            colModel:[
              {name:'id',index:'id', width:90, sorttype:"int", editable: true},
              {name:'name',index:'name', width:150,editable: true, editoptions:{size:"20",maxlength:"30"}},
              {name:'stock',index:'stock', width:60, editable: true, edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
              {name:'ship',index:'ship', width:90, editable: true, edittype:"select",formatter:'select',
        editoptions:{value:"FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX"}},         



       {name:'note',index:'note', width:200, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea",
    editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"10"}}                      
                  ],
        onSelectRow: function(id){
          if(id && id!==lastsel2){
            jQuery('#rowed5').editRow(id,true);
             alert("hi");

//---here i missed alert after clicking this i want to focus on the cell that the user had already clicked--
             setTimeout(function(){celValue.focus();},1);
//--here i get the particular cell value and i try to focus after clicking the alert box---- 

//-- i also try with $(this).focus as setTimeout(function(){$(this).focus();},1); but i did not get any possible output----             
    }
        },

        caption: "Input Types"
      });
      var mydata2 = [
        {id:"12345",name:"Desktop Computer",note:"note",stock:"Yes",ship:"FE"},
        {id:"23456",name:"Laptop",note:"Long text ",stock:"Yes",ship:"IN"},
        {id:"34567",name:"LCD Monitor",note:"note3",stock:"Yes",ship:"TN"},
        {id:"45678",name:"Speakers",note:"note",stock:"No",ship:"AR"},
        {id:"56789",name:"Laser Printer",note:"note2",stock:"Yes",ship:"FE"},
        {id:"67890",name:"Play Station",note:"note3",stock:"No", ship:"FE"},
        {id:"76543",name:"Mobile Telephone",note:"note",stock:"Yes",ship:"AR"},
        {id:"87654",name:"Server",note:"note2",stock:"Yes",ship:"TN"},
        {id:"98765",name:"Matrix Printer",note:"note3",stock:"No", ship:"FE"}
        ];
      for(var i=0;i<mydata2.length;i++)
        jQuery("#rowed5").addRowData(mydata2[i].id,mydata2[i]);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="rowed5" class="scroll"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You wrote that you want to "focus after clicking the alert box", but the code don't contains any alert. What you need to implement? Do you need to set focus on the cell which the user clicked? Do you need to set focus on the cell from specific column (like on "note" for example)?

Comment: yep i need to set the focus on the cell which the user clicked

Comment: i make some correction in my code and try to run it please refer my above code where i give my explanations please suggest me a solution

Comment: Look at [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) about formatting the code inside of the text. Minimal requirement is: you need insert empty row before and after text and to start every row of the code with 4 spaces or one tab,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the most simple solution if you would use the latest source of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which you can download from GitHub (free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid which I develop). It allows you to implement `onSelectRow` as below

```js
onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
    var $self = $(this), savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");

    if (savedRow.length > 0 && savedRow[0].id !== rowid) {
        //$self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
        $self.jqGrid("saveRow", savedRow[0].id);
    }

    $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, { focusField: e.target });
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/DhanaRaja1.htm). The `target` property of 3-d parameter of `onSelectRow` is the clicked element. One can use `focusField: e.target` option of `editRow` to set the focus on the input/select in the clicked cell.

If you need to use `alert` but you don't want to change the focus then you can save the current focus in a variable then call `alert` and set the focus on the element which had focus before calling `alert`:

```js
var $focused = $(":focus"); // get focus
alert("hi");
$focused.focus();
```

See the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/DhanaRaja2.htm).

Moreover I recommend you compare the modified code from my demo with your original code. For example it's very bad to fill the grid using `addRowData`. Instead of that one should use `data: mydata2` parameter of jqGrid.

Comment: very much thanks for your information and it is working