# Troubles adding inline CRUD to jqGrid table - what have I missed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, crud, inline-editing

Please take a look at this [prototype](https://secure.profitorius.com/dyn.table.3.html).

All the relevant client side code is visible on that page.  Here is the relevant server side code:

```
use Locale::Currency::Format;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $db = 'profitorius';
my $hostname = 'localhost';
my $user = 'me';
my $dbpwd = 'mypw';
my $dbh = DBI->connect_cached("DBI:mysql:database=$db;host=$hostname",$user,$dbpwd,{RaiseError => 1}) or die "Failed to connect to the DB.\n";

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $mid = $cgi->param('mid');


print $cgi->header(-type => 'text/xml;charset=latin1');
my $page = 1;
my $total_pages = 1;
my $s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='latin1'?><rows>";
$s .= "<page>".$page."</page>";
$s .= "<total>".$total_pages."</total>";
unless (defined $mid) {
    my $rcnt = 0;
    $s .= "<records>".$rcnt."</records></rows>";
    print $s;
    exit;
}
my $sql = "SELECT id, Product_name, price, customization, custom_price FROM merchant_products WHERE mid = $mid;";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;
my $tbl_ary_ref = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
my @ary = @$tbl_ary_ref;
my $rcnt = @ary;
$s .= "<records>".$rcnt."</records>";#<rows>
foreach my $v (@ary) {
    my @r = @$v;
    $r[2] = currency_format('USD',$r[2], FMT_HTML);
    $s .= "<row id='". $r[0]."'>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $r[0]."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $r[1]."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $r[2]."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $r[3]."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $r[4]."</cell>";
    $s .= "</row>";
}
$s .= "</rows>";
print $s;
exit;
```

I know the last column needs to be formatted as a currency, but that is not a problem.

1. My first problem is that, as you will notice, the buttons for
   adding, editing and deleting rows are not displayed.  I found TWO
   examples for adding these, for inline editing, but neither work. 
   How do I change the Javascript so that they are available?
2. My second problem, which I can't investigate until I get my first problem
   resolved, is a question of how to handle rows that have been added,
   edited, or deleted, once the edit is complete.  If I want to use a
   separate CGI script to handle row additions, row deleting and row
   updates, how are these specified in the creation of the grid?  If I
   handle such changes within the same CGI script that populates the
   grid, in what ways do I change that?  It is hard to say because all
   the examples I have found are in PHP, and I know just enough PHP to
   be dangerous.
3. My next problem involves capturing and processing onchange events when
   the inline editor is a  control.  Ultimately, I will set (in a 
   different grid)one of the inline editors to a select control, and I will 
   want to set the values in two or three other fields (readonly fields as 
   far as the user is concerned - only my Javascript code being able to 
   change the values in these fiends) based on what item is selected from 
   the select control.  Part of the problem, here, is how to represent the 
   idea of a map (from C++ or Java) or hash (from Perl) in Javascript.
4. My last problem focuses on data management.  Does the data have to be
   saved to the server when it is entered, as the user finishes editing one
   row, or is it possible to have the changes all stored in the DOM and
   saved all at once, when the form data, of which the table is a small
   part, is submitted for processing?  Can you point me to an example
   for either option?  If I must save each row as it is changed, it is
   not yet clear to me how to keep the table data for each
   user/session distinct from all the rest.

Clearly I must have missed something in the jqGrid documentation, but the question is what.

Thanks

Ted

Comment: First of all you should replace `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#list",...` to `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",...` to see edit buttons. Seconds it would be better to return JSON data from the server instead of XML. You can/should add `loadonce: true` option to the grid and `forceClientSorting: true` if you would use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.1 instead of retro version 4.5.0.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I have been plannng to upgrade jqGrid, but I am worried about having also to upgrade jQuery, as I am sure there are breaking changes in both.  I will do so eventually (probably Q2 or Q3 this year), but not yet.  Your suggestion worked, but now I get icons for both inline and form based editing.  Is it possible to show only those for inline editing? And do you have any suggestions for my remaining issues?

Comment: You use now `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager");` and have commented the line `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#list",{edit:false,add:false,del:false});`, which uses the options `{edit:false,add:false,del:false}` preventing form editing icons. Which version of jQuery you use now? Free jqGrid 4.13.1 have the same requirements to jQuery like 4.5.0. You can try just change the URLs of `ui.jqgrid.css`, `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and `grid.locale-en.js` to URLs from CDN described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).

Comment: I now have the number of icons displayed fixed (so I have only inline ones, plus the form one for a deletion), but am trying to figure out how to set a separate UL for each action: add, edit, delete.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I am using jquery-1.9.1.min.js.  I am constrained to downloading and hosting locally any Javascript library I use, for security reasons (the security standards we must code to are quite strict about not pulling resources from the web in our production environment).  Even hosting my template page for this on our production environment would cause lots of problems, not from a coding perspective but it is in violation of our security standards for our production environment.

Comment: Loading data over HTTPS from [the URLs](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#usage-cdn-with-integrity-attribute) is much more saver as from your local server. The answer on your other question and the next steps too heavy depend on version of jqGrid which you use. In retro version of jqGrid you can specify delete url in 5-th parameter of `navGrid`: `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#list",{edit:false,add:false,del:false}, {}, {}, {url: "deleteUrl"});` and using `editParams: {url:"editUrl"}` and `addParams : {addRowParams: {url:"addUrl" } },`

Comment: I have two remaining problems, for now.  1) editurl:"clientArray", and cellsubmit:"clientArray" on the top grid are not permitting me to edit the grid data locally.  Do they not work with XML data?

Comment: 2) on the second grid, I am trying to populate three cell contents based on what is selected in the product column.  Alas, while the CGI script that returns the required JSON, Javascript sees it only as an object and is refusing to parse the data out of the JSON object.  When I look at the data sent by the CGI script, it is correct, with the right data and right header, but I get this: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
 

...unction(n){return e.JSON&&e.JSON.parse?e.JSON.parse(n):null===n?n:"string"==type..."

Comment: I suppose that the JSON data have wrong syntax. You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate the data. If you will have problem with interpretation of the error message you should append the text of your question with the test JSON data.

Comment: Writing `$s .= '{"id"="'. $r[0].'","Product_name"='". $r[0]."}';` (full code will be a little longer) will generate JSON instead of XML. You should understand that jQuery don't oriented on processing common XML data and sending XML instead of JSON have many disadvantages, for example performance.

Comment: You wrote before "I am trying to figure out how to set a separate UL for each action: add, edit, delete." Thus I send you how to do this. Local editing is possible too. The only disadvantage could be simultaneous editing of the same data from different computers. It the case is not important then you can use local editing and get the final results by `$("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");`

Comment: My JSON is dirt simple: {"custom_price":"0","customization":"","price":"99.95"}   http://jsonlint.com/ identifies it as valid, but then, this case is so simple, it would be hard to get wrong.  I wonder if the response headers might be a problem:

Connection     Keep-Alive
Content-Type   application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date           Fri, 18 Mar 2016 20:03:33 GMT
Keep-Alive     timeout=5, max=100
Server        Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3
Transfer-Encoding   chunked

Is there a simple way to remove the headers from 'data' before passing it to the parser?

Comment: Yes, I have two different use cases, one of which involves separate CGI scripts for each operation and the other involves local editing, if that is possible.  In the use case involving local editing, there is no possibility that two users may want to edit the same data at the same time (picture e.g. a customer service representative talking with a customer and completing a form representing the customer's order).

Comment: Thanks Oleg,  I am not lear on how to use the "$("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");" you mentioned.  Is that in the onselect event for a row?  Could I trouble you to possibly flesh that example out a bit, so I know what attributes I need st and where to put that statement?

Comment: You are welcome! I'm not sure which code you use currently. You can change `datatype: "xml"` to `datatype: "json"` and to return the response from the serve in the form `[{"id":"1","Product_name":"Wall Lamp","price":"$34.99","customization":"Enhanced","custm_price":"6.75"},
{"id":"2","Product_name":"Ceiling Light","price":"$24.95","customization":"","custm_price":"0"}]`. The `Content-Type` should be `application/json; charset=utf-8`. I'm not sure which code you want to use in `onSelectRow`. You can have for example the button, with `.click` handler which get local `data` and send to server.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. You're looking at the wrong grid. I am not looking at changing my use of XML at the moment, for initially populating the grid. My reason is, it presently works, and if it ain't broke, don't fix it.  Can you focs on the second grid, and the ajax call in the onchange event for the select control.  In that call, I get the product ID (the value in the select control), and pass that, with an identifier that identifies the user, to my CGI script which in turn, returns the product's price, optional customization, and customization cost, in the JSON string I showed above. ajax here fails.

Comment: The `success` handle contains `var d = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` which is wrong because `data` is already object and not the string which need be parsed. You should use `data.price` directly. You should first get the id of the row inside of `change` handler, but **out of** `$.ajax`: `var rowid = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");` and then use `$("#" + rowid + "_price").val(data.price);` to change the value in input element of the row. You can use ` $("#list2").jqGrid("setCell", rowid, "price", data.price)` if `"price"` column **not editing**.

Comment: In any way you should add `idPrefix` to the second grid with some unique value to have no conflicts between ids of the second row and the first one.

Comment: Look at [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/byygepy3/11/), which I created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34976517/315935). It demonstrates the main idea, how one can implement editing of local data and then get only *modified* rows from the grid. Instead of `alert` one would of cause use `$.ajax` on click on `"Save Changed"` button.

Comment: ALMOST DONE!  One of the things I have not yet found is precisely what the CGI scripts, that ought to handle addition of rows, editing rows and deleting rows, should return once the operation completes.  And related to this, "Does the grid automatically reload the data once the specified operation succeeds?"

Comment: Another problem arises, logically prior to what my CGI scripts ought to return (the specific contents/headers for the response they produce), and that is I get the following error:   "TypeError: b.addParams.addRowParams.extraparam is undefined
https://secure.profitorius.com/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js
Line 407"  How can this be fixed, or worked around?

Comment: No, for inline editing mode and yes for for editing mode (even for deleting the row). If you want to reload the grid you should use `aftersavefunc` callback, which do the following `setTimeout(function() { $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid"); },50);`

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I think the error I reported last is preventing the data from being sent to my CGI script.  Once that is resolved, what should this return after the data is edited or updated?  I would assume the usual JSON header, but what should the content be?

Comment: you should **never** assign variable before declaring in JavaScript. You should add `var` before `parameters`. I recommend you to start the outer with `"use strict";` to find such errors very quickly: `$(function () {"use strict"; /*your other code here*/});`

Comment: To locale the errors like `b.addParams.addRowParams.extraparam` you should first of all to use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`, start Developer Tools of IE/Crome/Firefox and debug the code. I suppose it's a bug in the retro version of jqGrid, which you like so much. To be able to fine a workaround for the bug you should debug the code.

Comment: As an experiment, I tried jqGrid v 5.1.0 (apparently the latest version). The good news is that it seems to work with the old version of jQuery I am using (I already know that jQuery has breaking changes between the version I am using an the latest). The bad news is that my error related to b.addParams is now replaced by "TypeError: z.editoptions.value is undefined
https://secure.profitorius.com/jquery.jqGrid-5.1.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js
Line 1003" It is quite late, so I am tired and will search this error, and try to debug it, in the morning. That said, I'd appreciate any insights into this.

Comment: After [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438) the post announced changing the license agreement and changing the name of jqGrid to *commercial* Gurrido jqGrid JS (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)), I started to develop my own fork [free jqGrid](github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I continue to provide under MIT/GPL-licenses. I fixed a lot of bugs in old version, have implemented many features and just simple improvements to simplify the usage of jqGrid. I suggest you to verify whether some problem exist in **free jqGrid**.

Comment: If some problem exist in free jqGrid, then you should provide the demo, which uses *non-minimized* version of free jqGid (`jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) and to describe the test case (step by step instruction to reproduce the problem). You can look through [the old issues](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues) reported in the last year. I fixed the bugs typically in some hours or at least very quickly. If you prefer to use Gurrido jqGrid JS then you should report the problems to [Guriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4). You can read old issues posted to see the quality support.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I had no idea the license on jqGrid had changed, nor that you'd made a fork of it.  I will test and let you know.

Comment: Well thanks Oleg.  Now it mostly works.  I see one problem and have a question.  If you look at my second table, you will see the URL for the add, edit and delete operations is "/cgi-bin/example2edit.pl?mid=1&uid=1".  However, when I look at the request parameters received by example2edit.pl, there are values for each of the editable fields, but the dummy values I gave mid and uid are missing.  The mid and uid request parameters are not even there.  Why?  What  I find still missing from the documentation is what I ought to have example2edit.pl return: what header(s) and what content.

Comment: You are welcome! You use `editParams: { url:"/cgi-bin/example2edit.pl?mid=1&uid=1"}`, but you use HTTP Method "POST", which place the other data in the *body* of the sent request. You can use `editParams: {url:"/cgi-bin/example2edit.pl", extraparam: {mid:1, uid:1 }}` instead. Then the `mid` and `uid` will be sent in the body together with other parameters (`Product_name`, `quantity`, `discount`, `upgrade`, `oper` and `id`).

Comment: I'd recommend you to use HTML5 instead of old XHTML 1.0 Strict. You can add `<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">` to have no error about non-existing `https://secure.profitorius.com/favicon.ico`. You wrote about the quality of your web site. I'd recommend you to examine https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=secure.profitorius.com which gives your site C and https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/?id=e92dd192e7ced0291865a67f981ca4c160926ead3d0dd077f01e0764e7dcc439, which gives B-. I'd recommend to examine the reasons and to read https://isTlsFastyet.com/

Comment: Moreover your web site support only an old HTTP 1.1 protocol and no compression is enabled (Deflate, Gzip and no modern Brotli or SDCH). I'd recommend you to upgrade from Apache 2.4.10 to the current [2.4.18](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24), use mod_http2 module , existing starting with 2.4.17, which enables HTTP/2. HTTP/2 alone allows to improve the performance at least in 30%. Additionally one can use HTTP hush to improve the performance essentially. It's easy to use if you use PHP. One need just set HTTP header of response which contains `Link` header.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  That addresses the question of missing request parameters.  I am aware of ssllabs.com service, and will make a note of isTIsFastyet.com.  The machine my test page is hosted on is not my production system.  It is now only for testing new code.  In any event, you still have aid nothing about what response header example2edit.pl ought to return and what content.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm writing now suggestions to improve web development process for one large company and TLS analyse, the usage of HTTP/2, usage of Brotli compression additionally to old GZip and Deflate and many other aspects are common problem. Many large companies need upgrade his infrastructure and some processes in the web development, especially to be able to use HTTP/2, which is extremely  important and which require to change old web optimization to get the maximal speed. By the way, the grade of SSL of cdnjs.cloudflare.com is of cause A.

Comment: Thanks.  What you're doing is important (if you have a write up of your thoughts on web development, I'd love to see it). I will certainly verify that we're supporting HTTP/2 and Brotli compression on our production machine, but that is not my present task.  We do only support TLS1.2 on our production machine.  **That said, I am still looking for information of what  the response ought to be from my example2edit.pl: what response header and what content.  I do not need sample code for this.  I need only a specification of what header(s) are required and what content must be returned.**

Comment: See [the old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server). **No content is required** for responses on inline editing if saving is successful. You should return the error description and some error HTTP code in case of error.

Comment: OK, thanks.   I have this working, except for delete.  Is it possible, in the delete operation, to pass the value in the select control (Product_name), instead of or in addition to, the row ID?

Comment: It's possible in different ways. For example you can use `onclickSubmit` callback of Delete operation `delGridRow` and return from the callback any data which you want to send additionally (like `{Product_name: "Wall Socket"}`). Additionally, I'd recommend you to use `$(this)` in all callbacks instead of `jQuery('#list')` or `$("#list2")`. For example the grid 2 have the bug it use `jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);` (start editing **the first grid**). By the way, `$(this)` work of cause more quickly as `jQuery('#list')`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I tried following your suggestion regarding using aftersavefunc.  Alas, it does not seem to be triggered.  I am not sure if I have them in the wrong place, or what the problem may be.  Any ideas as to what me be awry?

Comment: You are welcome! You wrote that you wanted to send additional parameter during **deleting**, but I don't see that you included any `onclickSubmit`. Moreover you added `aftersavefunc` which code is wrong. you use `aftersavefunc: function() {var grid = $("#list2"); reloadgrid(grid); alert("aftersave fired for add");}`, but no global `reloadgrid` function exist. Correct would be to use something like `aftersavefunc: function() { var $self = $(this); setTimeout(function () { $self.trigger("reloadGrid");}, 50}; }`