# JqGrid Inline Adding Record Save

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

I've gone through many of the questions regarding adding records inline in JqGrid but I haven't been able to figure it out. I have inline editing working and adding a record using a modal popup.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 with EF.

I have the add button already working with a modal popup and the record saves to the database, but what I need is for an empty line to be added to the end of the grid (which I have working) and for the record to save to the database when the enter key is pressed after the fields have been entered. Thank you in advance for your help!

I'm using jqgrid version 4.4.4.

Here is the create method I'm currently using in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Create([Bind(Exclude = "TRANS_ID")] TRANSACTIONS_DETAIL tcrdetails)
    {
        string msg;
        try{
            ModelState.Remove("TRANS_ID");
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.TRANSACTIONS_DETAIL.Add(tcrdetails);
                db.SaveChanges();
                msg = "Saved Successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Validation data not successfull";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            msg = "Error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

I have inline editing working as you can see in this next code block:

```
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: "/Transactions/GetTransactions/",
    /*url: "/Transactions/GetTransactions/@ViewBag.hohupi",*/

    addParams: {
        position: "afterSelected",
        addRowParams: {
            // the parameters of editRow used to edit new row
            keys: true,
            oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
                alert("new row with rowid=" + rowid + " are added.");
            }
        }
    },

    //url for inline edit
    editurl: "/Transactions/Modify",
    //event for inline edit
    onSelectRow: function(currentSelectedRow){
        if(currentSelectedRow && currentSelectedRow != $.lastSelectedRow){
            //save changes in row 
            $('#grid').jqGrid('saveRow', $.lastSelectedRow, false);
            $.lastSelectedRow = currentSelectedRow; 
        }
        //$('#grid').jqGrid("inlineNav", "#pager", { addParams: { position: "last" } });
        $('#grid').jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', { addParams: { position: "last" } });
        //trigger inline edit for row
        $('#grid').jqGrid('editRow', $.lastSelectedRow, true);
       // $('#grid').jqGrid('addRow', $.lastSelectedRow, true);
    },
```

The following code has been one of my many attempts to get the inline adding working. I got the blank row to add, but I can't get it to save when pressing enter after all the fields have been entered:

```
    .navButtonAdd('#pager',{caption:"ADD", buttonicon :'ui-icon-circle-plus',onClickButton:function(id){
var newID=1;
$("#grid").find("tbody tr").each(function(){if(newID<=parseInt(this.id)){newID=parseInt(this.id)+1;}});
var datarow = {

    HOH_UPI: "", ICI: "", BILL_QTR: "",
    BNFT_YR: "", BNFT_MTH: "", AMOUNT: "", TRANS_TYPE: "",
    CHECK_NMB: "", CHK_DT_RCVD: "", ENTRY_DT: "", NAME_ON_CHECK: "",
    INDV_BATCH_NMB: "", USER_INIT: "", RTN_CHK_DT: "", LATE_DT: "",           FINAL_DT: "", COMMENTS: "", Modified_date: ""

};
var su=jQuery("#grid").addRowData(newID,datarow,"last");
if (su)       {jQuery("#grid").editRow(newID,true);jQuery("#grid").saveRow(newID,false);}}, title:"Add_new_row", position:"last" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which problem you have exactly. In any way the usage of `inlineNav` in retro version 4.4.4 is very bad idea, because old version contains many bugs. I suggest you to upgrade to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.1 and use new style of editing options described detailed in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods). By the way `position: "afterSelected"` is already implemented in free jqGrid

It's important to use `inlineNav` *one* and not inside of `onSelectRow`. Try just to use the option

```
inlineEditing: { keys: true }
```

which allows to specify default options of **any calls** of `editRow`, direct inside of `onSelectRow` and indirect, which do `inlineNav`.

Additionally I'd recommend you to use built-in `"savedRow"` parameter of jqGrid instead of `lastSelectedRow`. You can move the part of the code from `onSelectRow` to `beforeSelectRow` like described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34976517/315935). It will do correct actions in case of errors in `saveRow`, for example validation errors.

I think that no additional `navButtonAdd` will be needed. In any way I'd recommend you *to remove* `<div id="pager"></div>` from HTML markup of your page and to use `pager: true` option instead of `pager: '#pager'`. By call of `navGrid`, `inlineNav` and `navButtonAdd` you can *skip* the parameter `'#pager'`. Free jqGrid detect the type of the parameter and will automatically use the pager of the grid.

I'd recommend you finally to use Font Awesome and optionally Bootstrap instead of jQuery UI CSS. Free jqGrid supports all the features.