# jqGrid Hidden Attribute for Modal Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using a modal pop up for adding new records, but I'm using inline for editing current records. When adding new records I want to hide some of the columns in the modal pop up.

If I set a column to hidden: true or editable: true then it also does not appear in the grid. What is the best way to hide columns in the add model pop up but still have them show in the grid?

Update to Oleg's Answer (setting editable attribute as function and testing hidden):

```
    {
            key: false, name: 'FINAL_DT', index: 'FINAL_DT',
            editable: true, formatter: 'date',
            formatoptions: { newformat: 'm-d-Y' },
            formoptions: {},
            editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validDateCheck },
             editable: function (options) {
                if (options.mode === "addForm")
                {
                    hidden = true;
                }
            },
            editoptions: {
                dataInit: function (element) {
                    $(element).datepicker({
                        id: 'finalDt_Datepicker',
                        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
                        //minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
                        maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                        showOn: 'focus'
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depend on the version of jqGrid and from the fork, which you use. The most simple solution would be if you upgrade to the latest version (4.13.1) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (it's the fork, which I develop). If you installed old version via NuGet, then you should uninstall it and install free jqGrid from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid). You can use it from [CDN](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) or [download](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/releases) locally.

Free jqGrid allows to define `editable` attribute as a function. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) for details. You can test return `"hidden"` value from `editable` callback if `options.mode === "addForm"`.

Comment: Thank you! Your answers are life saving! I've updated my question with some code. I'm testing the options.mode to be addForm and setting hidden to true. This hides the column in the modal form pop up, but does not hide it in the grid. However, it is now not editable in the grid.

Comment: I'm using jqgrid 4.4.4. Will I need to use your fork or can I get it working with this version?

Comment: @vmil: You wrote in your question: "What is the best way to hide columns in the add model pop up but still have them show in the grid". You wrote: "it is now not editable in the grid." What you mean? Which test case you mean exactly? You can test the `options.mode` for form editing, inline editing and return back the value which you want in the scenario. I implemented the feature `editable` as callback (and many other features described in readme to every version and in wiki) in free jqGrid. The feature not exit in retro version 4.4.4, which is dead.

Comment: I will look into changing over to free jqgrid. I didn't think 4.4.4 was very old though. I'm worried about how many changes I will have to make after upgrading. However, all of this could be avoided if my inline add would save when pressing enter, because I wouldn't have to use a the modal form add.

Comment: ...in regard to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071239/jqgrid-inline-adding-record-save