# printing changed rows in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

guys i am using jqgrid .. and i want to print changed rows in the grid .. here is my code

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Get Selected Rows" onclick="getSelectedRows()" /> 
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Get Changed Rows" onclick="getChangedRows()" />
  function saveAllRows(){
        getRowsData();
         var ids = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
         var i;
         for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('saveRow', ids[i]);
        }
       getRowsData();
    }

    function getRowsData(){
         var grid = $("#jqGrid"), rowData, temp= "";
         var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
         for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
             rowData = grid.getLocalRow(ids[i]);

             for (var item in rowData ) {
                if(item == 'RowData'){
                    break;
                }
                 temp += rowData[ item ] + ', ';
              } 
         }

         alert(temp);

    }
    function getChangedRows(){
         // comparing between the getRowData() before and after saving 
     }
```

so what i did is getting the the row data after and before saving ... so what i want to write in the `getChangedRows()` is comparing between the 2 getRowData() .. any help .. thansk alot

Comment: I thing that "printing" is the wrong word. On the other side the other important things are not clear enough. One can see for example that you use *inline editing* in the code (and not cell editing or form editing). It's unclear *how you start editing* and whether you allow to edit multiple rows at the same time. One can see that you use `getLocalRow` thus you use probably `datatype: "local"` or `loadonce: true` option. It's unclear, whether you use *local paging* of the data. The current code will fail to get any information from another pages. Could you explain what you do more detailed?

Comment: Look at the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/byygepy3/11/, which I created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34976517/315935). It shows one of possible implementation of "getChangedRows".